# Popping all items from Python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm wondering if there is a way to "pop all" items from a list in Python?

It can be done in a few lines of code, but the operation seems so simple I just assume there has to be a better way than making a copy and emptying the original. I've googled quite a bit and searched here, but to no avail.

I realize that popping all items will just return a copy of the original list, but that is exactly why I want to do just that. I don't want to return the list, but rather all items contained therein, while at the same time clearing it.

```
class ListTest():
    def __init__(self):
        self._internal_list = range(0, 10)

    def pop_all(self):
        result, self._internal_list = self._internal_list[:], []
        return result

        # ... instead of:
        # return self._internal_list.pop_all()


t = ListTest()

print "popped: ", t.pop_all()
print "popped: ", t.pop_all()
```

... which of course returns the expected:

```
popped:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
popped:  []
```

Comment: You already found the way to do it; just clear the list.

Comment: This is exactly how it's done. Since popping all items means "copy, then empty", it makes no sense to have a method to do this.

Comment: Why is the code you've got displayed not sufficient?

Comment: It is sufficient, but I'm trying to learn here. There are ways of doing amazing things in Python using a single statement, so I assumed there is a pop_all() way to lists as well. I was wrong.

Comment: It would be good if you asked a specific question. While you led with a question you immediately answered it and left the reader wondering what you wanted to know.

Comment: I realize this is ancient.. but I have to comment.. that REPLACING a list.. is NOT the same as EMPTYING a list.  Because if you have got multiple references to the list in your code, the other references will still point to the original list.. not the new empty one.  This may not matter sometimes, but it's not the same...  I'm working on some multithreaded code right now where this absolutely makes a difference.  That's how I ended up reading this 7 year old question.

Comment: Does anyone have a way to pop all items atomically? Assuming a different thread could be inserting while I'm popping? I also want to preserve order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, why not just

```
def pop_all(self):
    result, self._internal_list = self._internal_list, []
    return result
```

... if you are reassigning `self._internal_list` anyway, why not just return the old one instead of copying it?

Comment: That is a very good point! It also means I'll not be copying my original. Should have thought of that, but it has been a long day.

Answer (score 11):

This is exactly how it's done. The only substantial improvement that I can think of is to empty the list in-place:

```
def pop_all(l):
    r, l[:] = l[:], []
    return r
```

The difference between this and your version is the behavior on a list that is referenced from various places:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> pop_all(a)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a need for this just now, and decided on using a list comprehension rather than have a subclass or subroutine like this:

```py
popped = [l.pop(0) for item in list(l)]
```

Comment: I also like doing this with an underscore to hint it's not being used and `range` to hint that we're not really looping over the list, we're calling `pop` `n` times.  Something like `[l.pop(0) for _ in range(len(l))]`